# I have an svg image and I want the link of the image to be looped but it only displays one image

Tags: php, loops, svg

THIS IS MY CODE BELOW

```
<?php $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cms_team`");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    { 
        $link = str_replace("../", "https://example.com/", $row["team_photo"]);
        if($row["team_order"]>0)
        {
 
            echo ' <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                 
                <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <defs>
                    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="140" height="140">
                      <image xlink:href="'.str_replace("../", "https://example.com/", $row["team_photo"]).'" x="-25" width="170" height="120" />
                    </pattern>
                  </defs>
                  <polygon id="hex" points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25" fill="url(#img)"/>
                </svg><br>
                <h2 style="color:#`ffffff`"><?=$row["team_name"];?></h2>
                <p style="color:#fff" class="mt-2"><?=$row["team_short_bio"];?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="#" style="color:#fff">View details</a></p>
                
               
             </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->';
 
        }
    }
?>
```

I NEED to create multiple svgs but it only gets the first image and creates its svg thus it replicates the same image over and over again

Comment: All id values must be unique so id="img" is going to be a problem if you create these in a loop.

Comment: I have looped and added an image id that is unique but now the images dont show but from the code atleast its rerencing different image links which shows some progress thanks alot